# What does "void();" as a separate statement mean in C++?

Tags: c++

How does this program get compiled fine?

```
int main() {
    void();  // Does this create a "void" object here?
}
```

I've tested both under MSVC and GCC. But `void` is an incomplete type. When you do the same for any other incomplete user-defined type,

```
class Incomplete;

int main() {
    Incomplete();  // Error saying "Incomplete" is incomplete.
}
```

Comment: `void` doesn't have a constructor.

Comment: @chris Yes, but it is like `int()` or `float()`.

Comment: @Alex: `int` and `float` don't have constructors either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`void` type is and has always been special. It is indeed incomplete, but it is allowed in many contexts where a complete type is typically expected. Otherwise, for one example, a definition of a `void` function would be invalid because of incompleteness of `void` type. It is also possible to write expressions of `void` type (any call to a `void` function is an example of such expression).

Even in C language you can use immediate expressions of `void` type like `(void) 0`. What you have in your code is just an example of C++-specific syntax that does essentially the same thing: it produces a no-op expression of type `void`.

Answer (score 11):

C++11 §5.2.3 [expr.type.conv]/2 goes into detail (emphasis mine):

> The expression T(), where T is a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier for a non-array complete object type or the (possibly cv-qualified) void type, **creates a prvalue of the specified type**, whose value is that produced by value-initializing (8.5) an object of type T; **no initialization is done for the void() case**.

It's just a prvalue of type `void`. No special initialization or anything like `int()` would have. A prvalue is something like `true`, or `nullptr`, or `2`. The expression is the equivalent of `2;`, but for `void` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 2):

It is allowed construction in C++ that type void could be used as a template argument.